# Why in IE, the uploaded PNG image has been recognized as PJPEG content-type (asp.net mvc 3)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I met now the strange behaviour in IE9.

I have a simple line of code written in C# for asp.net (with mvc 3) application:

```
   string ct = image.ContentType;
   // image is `HttpPostedFileBase` type
```

When I debug in IE9, the `ct` returns `image/pjpeg` when I selected a *png* file. I **didn't** rename that file from `1.jpg`/`1.jpeg` to `1.png`.

If I debug using Firefox/Chrome as browser then `ct = "image/png"`(that's correct)

Why the PNG file is seen as `image/pjpeg` content-type ?

How to solve this issue ?

Or it is a bug in IE ?

Comment: Is the file itself really a png? Or is it a jpg with incorrect file extension? This might be a content sniffing related issue.

Comment: I mentioned that I didn't renamed `jpg` to `png`. I used Photoshop and I saved as PNG not JPG/JPEG.